# How to see reputation gain by questions or answers?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, graphs

Is there a way I can see my reputation gain by my Questions and Answers separately?

Currently the "Reputation History" chart shows me both together, so I don't know which ones I'm better at!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your questions and answers into separate browser bookmark folders, then count how many there are.

Comment: At last a simple and no-pain solution! Thanks for the brilliantly simple idea.

Answer (score 5):

The recent activity envelope link always gives me what I need.

Comment: You can only go back so far (to last month?), but I agree with this being the best view for rep up and rep down.

Comment: @TheTXI: That is whole different problem then.

Comment: @Rich B - What I'm looking for is a way to tell if my answers are better than my questions, basically.

Comment: @Jeremy Rudd: Then do some analysis on the data dump.

Answer (score 3):

I would point you towards the [data dump](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/creative-commons-data-dump-aug-09/), where you can find which posts are questions or answers by their `PostTypeId` in the `posts` table. `PostTypeId = 2` is an answer, whereas `PostTypeId = 1` is a question.

Comment: That's not a very accurate solution except on the time periods that the dumps are for. Anything occuring after the dump would not be shown.

Comment: But it would show which he's better at (questions/answer). It doesn't sound like he needs the exact rep for each, but rather some sort of average score.